# Generating dynamic scale for Big Decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have xsd restriction on my percentage which is of type BigDecimal

```
<xs:simpleType name="PercentageRate">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:fractionDigits value="10"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="11"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Now I always want to ensure my total digits doesnt get more than 11 digits and scale needs to by dynamically updated based on number before decimal.
I have written below JAVA code , but i just wanted to know if there is a better way for implementing this :

```
        BigDecimal myNumber= resultSet.getBigDecimal("MY_NUM");
        String numbersBeforeDecimal = myNumber.toPlainString().split("\\.")[0];
        if(myNumber!= null){
            if(numbersBeforeDecimal.length() == 1){
                myNumber.setScale(10,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            }
            else{
                myNumber.setScale(8,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What if the number is, say, "1e-15"? Then you can't get along with 11 digits, unless you use exponential format, and then you'll have to cut a little more.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to ensure that total digits are 11

```
myNumber  = new BigDecimal(myNumber.toPlainString(), new MathContext(11, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Comment: That didnt work : tried with :
BigDecimal myNumber = new BigDecimal(-0.790833333333333);
BigDecimal rate = new BigDecimal("0.123456789012");
Result :